How do you access theme palette color channel with TypeScript in Material UI?
I read from the docs you can just do it like below:
const theme = createTheme({ cssVariables: true });
console.log(theme.palette.primary.mainChannel);

But since I use Material UI with typescript I got an error even thought it just work fine if I just ignore the error.
Property 'mainChannel' does not exist on type 'PaletteColor'.

So my question is how do you properly access it with TypeScript?

You need to augment it - https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/77231970920845103fb525c0ccc84b7cd5de2b43/apps/pigment-css-vite-app/src/augment.ts#L13-L20 -- basically create a .d.ts file and copy lines 13 to 20 (and include it in your tsconfig if .d.ts files aren't already included.)
